# Linked source folder in eclipse not working in other editors and terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, linker-errors, library-path

I am working in a java project which requires java3d and i unzipped the library from the website and placed the contents inside my project repositry as follows

```
lib:
j3dcore.jar  j3dutils.jar  vecmath.jar

resources:
libj3dcore-ogl.so
```

I opened Eclipse IDE and Included the class path and also changed the Native Library Location for those ones to resources directory and it was working fine in eclipse but when I switch to terminal or other debugging editors like VSCode,Atom It is not working and it shows like it is not linked to the .so file but the classpath stays included in all the platforms

please Help me what to do with this.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: but i want a standalone project which is independent of the files outside the directory and also independent of the platform I use.
I understand that the eclipse searches for the class file from the .classpath file
But I dont want that to happen either I want independency of platforms too..

Comment: As I repeatedly said many times - if you want to achieve that, make yourself familiar with how classpath is configured and how it is specified in command line. The easiest way is to simply examine what parameters eclipse is using.